# Error 400: Max error blob size is 10240 bytes

Tags: google-app-engine

When I try to update my `Google App Engine` app, I get the following error:

```
11:15 AM Rolling back the update.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Max error blob size is 10240 bytes.  Error blob "default" is 11875 bytes.
--- end server output ---
```

Any idea how to fix this?

**Note:**

I have deployed this app many times. I'm not sure what change I may have made to get this error.

**Note 2:**

I just ran appcfg.py with the --noisy option and I see the following generated line during the update attempt. I still don't know how to fix this.

2012-11-15 12:04:37,477 INFO appcfg.py:1575 Adding errorblob default (11874 bytes, type=text/html) to batch.

**Note 3:**
It turned out to be the following lines in the app.yaml file:

error_handlers:
- file: server-error.html

Please see http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3759.

I can now update the app again after commenting those lines out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the following lines in the app.yaml file:

error_handlers:
- file: server-error.html

Please see http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3759.

I can now update the app again after commenting those lines out.

Answer (score 0):

from http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

When certain errors occur, App Engine serves a generic error page. You can configure your app to serve a custom static file instead of these generic error pages, so long as the custom error data is less than 10 kilobytes

The issue is the SIZE of your server-error.html file itself.